# R - Checking homoscedasticity between sets

Tags: r

So I've got this school problem, which I'm really not able to guess how could I do it in R.

Is how to check if there is homoscedasticity between 3 different sets of ages.

Which contrast would help me to guess if there is homoscedasticity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using the `cars` dataset:

`lmMod <- lm(dist ~ speed, data=cars) # initial linear model`

Now, we can evaluate our model either graphically or statistically.

## Graphically:

We can plot the residuals versus either the fitted values or the leverage.
    par(mfrow=c(2,2)) # init 4 charts in 1 panel
    plot(lmMod)

Below are the plots. They are also in the R-Bloggers post linked at the bottom, from which I am getting most of this answer.
[image: Plots]

Anyways, we are interested in the top-left and bottom-right plots. In both of these plots, a flat, horizontal red line centered on 0 would indicate homoscadicity, while deviations from that indicate the presence of heteroscadicity.

## Statistically:

We can use the **Breusch Pagan Test** or the **NCV (Non-Constant Variance score) Test**.

### Breusch-Pagan Test (Studentized)

```
lmtest::bptest(lmMod)  # Breusch-Pagan test
studentized Breusch-Pagan test

data:  lmMod
BP = 3.2149, df = 1, p-value = 0.07297
```

### NCV Test

```
car::ncvTest(lmMod)  # Breusch-Pagan test
Non-constant Variance Score Test 
Variance formula: ~ fitted.values 
Chisquare = 4.650233    Df = 1     p = 0.03104933
```

As you can see, the p-value of the *studentized* Breusch-Pagan test was greater than 0.05, meaning that we could **not** reject the null hypothesis (that the data are homoscedastic). However, [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193061/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-breusch-pagan-tests) discussion on CrossValidated indicates that the NCV Test is the original version of the Breusch-Pagan Test, and thus more accurate.

Source: https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-detect-heteroscedasticity-and-rectify-it/

Comment: It would be better to include the plots inline, instead of a link

Comment: Corrected. Initially I didn't have enough reputation to post images, but now I can!

Comment: @Drew I know this is old, but for the sake of future readers coming from Google: Why would the original version of a test make it more accurate? Wouldn't more recent versions of old tests be more accurate instead? Indeed, the accepted answer on the [discussion you linked to](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/193070/195567) suggests the contrary: that the studentized Breusch-Pagan test is considered more **robust** than the original one.

Comment: @Drew What if the p-value of the studentized Breusch-Pagan test is greater than 0.05 but the lines in the plots residuals vs fitted and scale location are very far from being straight?